# @property for delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

A quick question if I may, can anyone explain what I am missing below, I was assuming the 3rd one with the  would work?

```
@interface ...
// These work
@property(assign) SomeClass *someDelegate;

@property(assign) id someDelegate;

// This gives warning
@property(assign) id  <SomeClassDelegate> someDelegate;
```

.

```
@implementation ...
@synthesize someDelegate;

[self setSomeDelegate:[[SomeClass alloc] init]];
[someDelegate setDelegate:self];
```

.

```
warning: method '-setDelegate:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

## EDIT_001:

```
// SomeClass.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class SomeClass;

@protocol SomeClassDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)didHappen:(SomeClass *)someClass;
@required
-(void)willUse:(SomeClass *)someClass withThis:(BOOL)flag;
@end

@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    id <SomeClassDelegate> delegate;
}
@property(assign) id <SomeClassDelegate> delegate;
-(void)otherActions;
@end
```

cheers Gary.

Comment: There's not enough code here - what's SomeClass and what's the definition for SomeClassDelegate? What warning do you get?

Comment: Added SomeClass.h, @synthesize and Warning:

Comment: I know this is a really good answer but I can't exactly get it to fit to my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go protocols!

```
@protocol MyDelegateProtocol
- (NSNumber*) someFunction:(NSArray*) anArray;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  id<MyDelegateProtocol> delegate;
}

@property id<MyDelegateProtocol> delegate

@end
```

Then in your @implementation:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

As far as I know, the Cocoa way :-)

Cheers

Nik

Comment: Hi, might I ask how you would instantiate that?

Comment: Sure, if the protocol is declared in MyClass.h, do in your controller header MyController.h (or wherever you want to use it) #import "MyClass.h", then in the @interface MyController line you add <MyDelegateProtocol> before the {, thus saying that this class implements MyDelegateProtocol. Then all you need is to implement in that class the protocol functions, in this case - (NSNumber*) somefunction:(NSArray*) anArray;

Answer (score 0):

Unless it exists and you didn't show it, you don't have a `setDelegate` method. You have a `setSomeDelegate` method, though.

Comment: Hi kubi, setDelegate is on the 3rd line under @implementation.